# Poor PHP ArrayObject design

Tags: php, arrays, class

Why are just a few PHP array functions are available in `ArrayObject` class as method? For example `asort()` is available but `walk()` and many others are not.

```
$s= new ArrayObject(array(1,3,4,5,6,4));
$x= $s->asort();                   //implemented
$x= $s->sum();                     //not implemented
$x= array_sum($s->getArrayCopy()); //not an OO manner!  
//sum is an example, consider:array_map,array_walk,array_merge ....
```

Please note that I have carefully read the documentation. My question is WHY php team just embedded a subset of array functions in `ArrayObject` class (that should encapsulate array related requirments). Isn't it a poor design?
Why we should extend this class and embed tens of function in this class again? Is is reasonable?

Comment: @Reza really i think it just comes down to being able to extend it yourself for self needs. You wouldn't use an array of numbers for ArrayObject anyway, hence the name Object in there. You can have a class collection, but how would you sum that up? you have to define it. Would you rather not have the array class?

Comment: duplicate of closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174430/arrayobject-class-in-php

Comment: @Reza, the answer to your question is *because that's what the author decided*. If you wish to know reasons, hopefully they can remember, then I can forward their contact details on to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what a collection of objects should be able to do natively and easily. If I have a collection of books, I want to be able to sort them, I want to be able to get one at a certain location, I want to be able to iterate through them, etc. What I don't want is to be able to add them all up. If I added a sum function to that object, it would mean that every instance of that object would also have a sum function -- a bizarre and unexpected use case for the most part.

`ArrayObject`, in a lot of senses, is  a lot closer to the idea of the traditional array than PHP's `array` ever managed. I believe it is supposed to be faster because of this.

Comment: Did you mean that ArrayObject is intended to an array of objects only? So it's name should be ObjectsArray!
I like use an OO class for all array type, like in Java.

Comment: No. It is an object which functions largely like an array. The thing is, arrays in PHP are not really arrays in the same sense that they are in, say, C or Java.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayObject is not just for array which has element like int/float that need to do a sum operation. array_sum is not necessary for all ArrayObject Type object. You should extend the `ArrayObject`, like `NumberArrayObject` to have a `sum` method.

Comment: sum is an example, What about other function.
PHP is not type-strong as you know

Comment: array_map,array_walk,array_merge ....

Answer (score 1):

*Everything on the [Array functions page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) breaks this Object Oriented principle.

*Everything that's not on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

The reason is simple: When PHP was created, there weren't many OOP standards they had in mind. OOP was added as an afterthought and improved in PHP5. When PHP created, primitives (and arrays) weren't treated as objects, so these functions existed. It certainly makes sense to couple functions with the datatypes they are associated with, but PHP will always keep it's original array functions.